# programming collective intelligence by toby segaran. How schema works?

Tags: python-2.7, search, search-engine, ranking, collective-intelligence

I am studying his schema but got confused how and to whom **"fromid"** from **link** is making a relation with inside **urllist**? or it is a misprint ? Its chapter 4 Searching and Ranking and figure 4-1. My eyes gone blind for as i have read so much but could not able to understand even the purpose of "fromid".

Here is the Book link as: http://www.uploadmb.com/dw.php?id=1447327761

[image]
Please help Thanks.

Comment: `fromid` and `toid` both reference the `rowid` in `urllist` - i.e. a `link` is from one URL to another.

Comment: then what does it shows. I mean do nt u think they then have same purpose?

Comment: What do you mean *"they then have same purpose"*? A link in that schema **connects two URLs**, so has an ID for each (`from` one `id`, `to` another `id`). What is unclear?

Comment: oh ok this means for example like in Google when i type Python so google picks up link from one id to another id? is that thing for example?

Comment: bcz in db i see (1,30) more than 2 times